# Strange behaviour with pandas.DataFrame.update

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes df1:

```
index   Value
0        A
1        B
2        Nan
3        D
4        Nan
```

And df2:

```
index   Value
2        C
4        E
```

In my jupyter notebook I use Pandas update function to fill in the missing values of df1 from df2. Using the following function:

```
def my_function(df, df_2):
    df1.update(df2)
    return
```

Because .update() modifies dataframes in place and has no return value, my functions also doen't return anything. The behaviour I don't understand occurs when I run the following code in jupyter notebook:

```
blaat = df1

my_function(blaat, df2)
```

Now not only the 'blaat' dataframe has been modified by the function but also df1. I don't understand why that is.

Comment: For me it working nice

Comment: Yes, it works but why are both 'blaat' and 'df1' dataframes modified by the function?

Comment: Because same object, if need different, need `blaat = df1.copy()`

Answer (score 1):

Assigining a variable holding a mutable object to another variable does not create a new object, it only creates an alias to the same object.

When you do

```py
blaat = df1
```

you are telling the interpreter that df1 and blaat are both the same objects (pointing to the same location in memory) but have two names.

So modifying blaat is the same as modifying df1.
You can confirm this by getting the memory address of both variables.

```py
id(blaat) == id(df1)
```

As noted in the comment, you must create a copy of df1 and assign that to blaat to create a new object and not just an alias to the same object.

```py
blaat = df1.copy()
```

As mentioned, this applies to all mutable objects in Python. So

```py
list_2 = list_1
id(list_2) == id(list_1)  # True

list_2 = list_1.copy()
# or
list_2 = list_1[:]

id(list_2) != id(list_1)  # True
```